# Prove that $A$ will always be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $n$ and $m$ are two positive integers and $\displaystyle A=\frac{n^2+m^2}{1+mn}$ is also a positive integer, then $A$ must be a perfect square.

I deduced that $n\ne m$ except for the case $n=m=1.$ Using some algebra we get, $$m^2 - (An)m + (n^2 - A)  = 0 $$
Using the quadratic formula, $$m=\frac{An\pm\sqrt{A^2n^2-4(n^2-A)}}{2}$$
Now what should I do$?$ I'm stuck. Also, can we find some relations using vietas formulas$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcaYEaVTA4g

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

Comment: @jjagmath I tried to flag as dupe but misclicked.